# deferred length character as actual arg

Tags: fortran, character

```
program as_actual_arg
    implicit none
    interface 
      subroutine as_actual1(defchar)
        implicit none
        character(len=*), intent(out) :: defchar
      end subroutine

      subroutine as_actual2(defchar)
        implicit none
        character(len=:), allocatable, intent(out) :: defchar
      end subroutine
    end interface

    character(len=:), allocatable :: defchar

    call as_actual1(defchar)
    print *, defchar
    call as_actual2(defchar)
    print *, defchar
end program


subroutine as_actual1(defchar)
    implicit none
    character(len=*), intent(out) :: defchar
    print *, 'length : ', len(defchar)

    defchar = "1234567890"
end subroutine

subroutine as_actual2(defchar)
    implicit none
    character(len=:), allocatable, intent(out) :: defchar

    defchar = "2345678901"
end subroutine
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
gfortran 4.8.2 on ubuntu 14.04

```
$gfortran as_actual_arg.f90 -std=f2003
$./a.out
length :        32767

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F83873497D7
#1  0x7F8387349DDE
#2  0x7F8386FA0FEF
#3  0x400B5C in as_actual1_
#4  0x400BB0 in MAIN__ at as_actual_arg.f90:?
```

### seg fault

ifort 14

```
$ifort as_actual_arg.f90 -stand=f03
$./a.out
 length :            0

 2345678901
```

and terminated in normal
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

what is the standard for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program is nonconforming - you call as_actual1 with an unallocated actual argument when the dummy argument is not allocatable.  ifort with appropriate debugging options will identify this at runtime.

Allocate the defchar variable in the main program (which also will specify the length of the variable) before calling as_actual1.

Comment: When you allocate a deferred length character variable, you have to give the variable a length (which might be the default of one) - perhaps you use an allocate statement like `ALLOCATE(CHARACTER(42) :: defchar)` or perhaps you use allocation on assignment or whatever.  Once it is allocated (and hence once it has a length), then you can pass it to a procedure with an assumed length dummy (as in as_actual1 - where the dummy has a * for its length specification) the assumed length dummy argument will assume the length of the actual argument.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by IanH, you will find it easier to develop your programs if you use the tools provide by the compilers.  Both gfortran and ifort find the problem if debugging compiler options are used:

gfortran:

```
At line 29 of file as_actual_arg.f90
Fortran runtime error: Allocatable actual argument 'defchar' is not allocated
```

Using compiler options:

```
-O2  -fimplicit-none  -Wall  -Wline-truncation  -Wcharacter-truncation  -Wsurprising  -Waliasing  -Wimplicit-interface  -Wunused-parameter  -fcheck=all  -std=f2008  -pedantic  -fbacktrace
```

ifort (old version):

```
forrtl: severe (408): fort: (7): Attempt to use pointer DEFCHAR when it is not associated with a target
```

using compiler options:

```
-O2  -stand f03    -assume realloc_lhs  -check all  -traceback  -warn all  -fstack-protector  -assume protect_parens  -implicitnone
```

Using this revision of your program:

```
module MyMod

contains

subroutine as_actual1(defchar)
    implicit none
    character(len=*), intent(out) :: defchar
    print *, 'length : ', len(defchar)

    defchar = "1234567890"
end subroutine

subroutine as_actual2(defchar)
    implicit none
    character(len=:), allocatable, intent(out) :: defchar

    defchar = "2345678901"
end subroutine

end module MyMod

program as_actual_arg
    use MyMod
    implicit none


    character(len=:), allocatable :: defchar

    call as_actual1(defchar)
    print *, defchar
    call as_actual2(defchar)
    print *, defchar
end program
```

which saves the effort of writing interface blocks.  With modules its automatic ... easy and reliable.